# How to efficiently compare two lists of Products

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, data-structures, hash

I'm trying to write a method that checks in an efficient way if 2 lists of products are equals.

```
List<Product> firstList = getProductsListFromSomewhere();
List<Product> secondList = getProductsListFromSomewhereElse();

public boolean areListsEqual(List<Product> firstList, List<Product> secondList) {
    ...
}
```

**Constraints and conditions**

- The same product can appear multiple times in the list. Ex. (Product A, Product B, Product A, Product C)
   This could represent a problem if I use an HashSet to store the content of the first list and then parse the second list to check if each Product is in the set because I can't put duplicates in the HashSet.
- The two lists are considered equals if they contains the same products and those appear the same number of times but their order is NOT relevant.
   So for example those two lists 
  (Product A, Product B, Product A, Product C)
   (Product C, Product A, Product A, Product B)
   are considered equals.
  But those two
  (Product A, Product B, Product A, Product C)
  (Product A, Product B, Product C)
  are considered different
- The object Product is defined as follows (note its code is autogenerated so I can't write the methods *equals* and *hashcode* inside its class)

  ```
  class Product {
      private String name;
      private Integer quantity;
      private List<Discount> discountsList;

      //some other field not needed for the comparison
  }
  ```
- Two products are considered equals if they have the same **name**, the same **quantity** and the same **discountsList**
- Also for the lists of discounts comparison the element's order is NOT relevant
- Discount is defined like this (also in this case the class is autogenerated  and I can't write the methods *equals* and *hashcode*)

  ```
  class Discount {
      String code;

      //some other field not needed for the comparison
  }
  ```
- Two discounts are considered equals if they have the same code

**Requirements and preferences**

- The comparison has to be efficient (I guess I have to use some kind of hashing)
- The code should be as clean as possible (I would prefer to avoid to use things like reflection to parse the structure etc)
- If possible I would prefer NOT to use external libraries

**My (not valid :( ) approach**
I started to write a draft of a possible solution but I found different blockers to my approach and I don't know if I should refine it in some way or completely rethink about it.
My idea is to extend the Product class inside the class that should perform the comparison:

```
List<Product> firstList = getProductsListFromSomewhere();
List<Product> secondList = getProductsListFromSomewhereElse();

public boolean areListsEqual(List<Product> firstList, List<Product> secondList) {
    ...
}  

private class ComparableProduct extends Product {

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    final ComparableProduct other = (ComparableProduct)obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.quantity, other.quantity)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.discountList, other.discountList)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
    hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.quantity);
    hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.discountList);
    return hash;
  }
}
```

This approach obviously doesn't work because the Discount object is compared without defining the equals and hashCode methods but I can't extend Discount because the discountList defined in the Product object is of Discount type so I can't use the ComparableDiscount eventually created. 
 Furthermore I don't know exactly what is the best way/data structure to use, once the hashing mechanism is defined, to check that the two lists are equals
Would you help me to complete this part of code in the best possible way?

Comment: Trying to subclass indicates that you have realized the problem. The whole issue comes from using DTOs (autogenerated stuff) as your business/domain objects. What I'd do in this case is create my own domain objects (without subclassing) and then use those. In the C# world I'd use a library like automapper to map between the DTOs and the domain objects, but surely there's something similar for Java? A quick search brought up a project called Dozer. Good luck!

Comment: Create two maps, each whose key is the given product and whose value is the count of occurrences in your lists... then compare the maps to each other

Comment: @RobOhRob The easiest way to create that map is to have a `hashCode` method on the keys, which leads you back to the approach that is currently failing.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to write a function that takes a `Product` and generates a unique string representation of it.  Be sure that if you consider two the same, you must get the same string out.  (For example sort the discount codes.)

Now you can turn a `List` of `Product` objects into a `List` of strings.  You can now compare two of these lists fairly easily.

One tip if these can be big is to actually work with an MD5 hash of the description rather than the description itself.  Those will be shorter and the odds of a collision are astronomically low.

If you want to actually identify the differences, you should store a map of the string representing the product to the product object.  That way once you know which strings are in one list but not the other, then you can turn strings back into objects before returning them.